# RTK MySql: how to split variable array into seperate entries

Tags: javascript, mysql, rtk-query

I have

```
const {data, error, isLoading } = useFetchBulkClassesQuery(something)
```

to pass data to MySql via this API:

```
fetchBulkCclasses: builder.query ({
                query: (something) => {
                    return {
                        url: '/bulkclasses',
                        params: {
                            class: something
                        },
                        method: 'GET'
```

at the backend, I have

```
tyapp.get("/bulkclasses", (req, res) => {
    const q = 'select * from recent where ticker in (?)'
    db.query(q, [[req.query.ticker]], (err, data) => {
        if(err) {return res.json(err)}
        return res.json(data)pe here
```

it al works fine if I use a single variable, like something = 'ClassA'
But I want to use it for multiple entries like ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ...
But it only takes the first one (or the last one depending on what I try).

What am I doing wrong? Or what haven't I tried (or what do I not know)?

I tries:

- Something = ['ClassA', 'ClassB', ...] -> the thing that get passed to the backend is 'ClassA, ClassB' en and it needs to be 'ClassA', 'ClassB', ...
- Something = [[ClassA], [ClassB],...] -> same result

Comment: I think your ticker parameter is just a string that happens to contain multiple comma separated values. You may need to turn that into an array or list as a minimum before using it as a parameter.

Comment: No, it is an array for sure.
No matter how I format it ( like [['classA', 'classB']] or [['classA'],['classB']] or even [[['classA], ['classB']]] ), the backend side keeps on receiving it is 'classA, classB'. And it needs to be 'classA', 'classB' 
The 'ticker" in the nodejs-part is a leftover from the original code, I forgot to change it. Over there I also tried with brackets, without brackets, ... Passing a single entry works fine, but I need to pass multiple variables.
Btw, I'm using the mysql2 package

Answer (score 0):

It seemed a bit impossible to do, so I did choose the easiest solution: changing the design of my tables and update the query.